# I get an error when I try to get a site in Python

Tags: python, whois

```
import whois
site = input('enter site : ')
M = whois.whois(site)
print(M)
```

---

When I input,
`enter site : google.com`

I got following response (error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Programming/project/Project/whois.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whois
  File "f:\Programming\project\Project\whois.py", line 4, in <module>
    M = whois.whois(site)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: The file path in the stack trace isn't where modules would usually be installed. Do you have a module called whois?

Comment: Which python version are you using? Did you install the module with pip?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
M = whois.query(site)
print(M.__dict__)
```

`query` is the method to get the site whois data

Answer (score 1):

Your file is called `whois.py`. When you import `whois` you are importing your file not the package you think you are. Running `whois.whois(...)` you are calling yourself as a function.

Rename your file and try again.

Comment: I changed it before, it gives an error again

Comment: No module named 'whois'

Comment: @MiladRasooli how did you install `whois`?

Comment: pip install whois